# How can I see my changes without application restart from Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

I have a question: We in our team have been developing with grails for years and we love grails. We wanted to update our Grails version, before we do that, we also wanted to consider Micronaut and make a comparison. We can actually work just as well with the Micronaut Framework.

The only thing that bothered us as a team was Development Live Updating of the code. That works almost flawlessly with grails. But that's not the case with the Micronaut. If you do bigger projects, that would be very annoying. we haven't found a real way to do that either.

Live updating of the code means seeing the changes without restarting the server.

Doesn't Micronaut currently have anything like that?
Not planned either?
Or am I completely wrong and Microanut supports something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't Micronaut currently have anything like that?

Micronaut does currently have something like that.

> Or am I completely wrong and Microanut supports something like that?

Our reloading support is documented at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.3.1/guide/index.html#reloading.

Answer (score 0):

'./gradlew run -t' recompiles but also restarts the application

Answer (score 0):

For Intellij you have to press ctlr + F9 every time.

For Eclipse you can go to Project -> Build Automatically and check the box.

This will recompile when you save changes.